# One servlet passing string to another servlet via http post

Tags: java, servlets

I'm sending a string from one servlet to another via http url connection:

```
final HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();     // here url is the url of the second servlet
http.setRequestMethod("POST");
http.setDoOutput(true);
http.setDoInput(true);
http.setUseCaches(false);
final OutputStream outstr = http.getOutputStream();
outstr.write(sb.toString().getBytes());
outstr.flush();
outstr.close();
```

the problem I'm facing is in reading this as a request from another servlet. I tried to write the following code in getPost method of second servlet, but this doesnt work:

```
try {
        int len = req.getContentLength();
        byte[] input = new byte[len];
        ServletInputStream sin = req.getInputStream();
        int c, count = 0;
        while ((c = sin.read(input, count, input.length - count)) != -1) {
            count += c;
        }
        sin.close();
        String inString = new String(input);
        String decodedString = URLDecoder.decode(inString, "UTF-8");
        log.info("Response received - ");
        log.info(decodedString);
        resp.getWriter().write(decodedString);
        resp.getWriter().flush();
        resp.getWriter().close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
```

Can someone help what is the right way to get the string sent by the first servlet and display it?

Comment: Define "this doesn't work". What *exactly* are you getting? what happens?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your string as parameter in servlet that post and read it in servlet that receive as parameter.

Servlet that post:

```
outstr.write(("your_param=" + sb.toString()).getBytes());
```

Servlet that receive:

```
String yourParamValue = request.getParameter("your_param");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it should work this out

```
try {

        BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
        StringBuilder inputStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            inputStringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");

        }

        String requestData = inputStringBuilder.toString();
        reader.close();

        resp.getWriter().write(requestData);
        resp.getWriter().flush();
        resp.getWriter().close();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStacktrace();
    }
```